# change updating form fields

Tags: python, flask

I just started out in python, trying to build a python calculator code from a javascript code

basically when user changes a select field to "metric", some form labels change to 'Cms'

can anybody fix it?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
field_id = driver.find_element_by_id(id)

if  (field_id = 'msf').value == 'metric' :

    return (field_id = 'thf').innerHTML = ' (Cms)'

    (field_id = 'tneck').innerHTML = ' (Cms)'

    (field_id = 'twaist').innerHTML = ' (Cms)'

    (field_id = 'thips').innerHTML = ' (Cms)'

 else :

    (field_id = 'thf').innerHTML = ' (inches)'

    (field_id = 'tneck').innerHTML = ' (inches)'

    (field_id = 'twaist').innerHTML = ' (inches)'

    (field_id = 'thips').innerHTML = ' (inches)'
```

Comment: Isn't that what you want? What is the issue?

Comment: it doesn't work